# When i customize div tag size it automatically float left and lost the mobile phone responsiveness

Tags: html, css

this is the class that i had customize to adjest div tag size 
and i had added margins for keep div tag elements center

```css
.adjest-widht {
  width: 900px;
  position: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
```

**strong text**enter.

Comment: You need to add more code for us to understand the problem. The HTML and an illustration would be fine.

Comment: if you want to center your add `margin:auto;`

Comment: i had fixed  it . thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.adjust-width{width: 100%; max-width: 900px; margin:0 auto;  background: red;}
.mobile-width{width:80%; max-width:900px; margin:0 auto; background:green}
@media (max-width:767px){
.adjust-width{width:80%;}
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Center</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="adjust-width">
         <h1>Center</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mobile-width">
         <h1>Mobile</h1>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i fixed the issue ...reason is the particular view had already  imports a css class with a height and width.So i just remove the class from angular model.And now its working as i expect.Thank you very much